# What happens to federal debt that passes to a collection agency and gets removed from credit reporting agencies?

Tags: united-states, debt

Do medical bills from federal or state funded hospitals that have gone to a collections agency and subsequently removed from my credit report still have to be paid to the government?

Comment: I think it depends on how they were transferred to collection agency.  If the agency is acting as an agent of the hospital, then it depends on whether the agent is empowered to write off the debt on behalf of the hospital.  If the debt is sold to the collections agency, then the hospital is no longer involved.  Finally, medical debt is surrounded in regulations and protections.  These vary from state to state.  You need to consult with an expert who is on your side.